# Getting Nodes as per particular node value in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, nodes

I am new to XSLT. I have the following XML and I want to get nodes where `<fs>HD</fs>`
My Original XML is

```
<rfs>
    <rf id="1111">
        <FO>Al</FO>
        <recs>
            <rec id="1111_1">
               <t>N</t>
                <cf>AS</cf>
                <ref>S123</ref>
                <fs>APCT</fs>
            </rec>
            <rec id="1111_2">
               <t>N</t>
                <cf>AS</cf>
                <ref>S1231</ref>
                <fs>HD</fs>
            </rec>
            <rec id="1111_3">
               <t>N</t>
                <cf>AS</cf>
                <ref>S1232</ref>
                <fs>HD</fs>
            </rec>
        </recs>
        <Ag>XYZ</Ag>
    </rf>
     <rf id="2222">
        <FO>Sd</FO>
        <recs>
            <rec id="2222_1">
               <t>N</t>
                <cf>AS</cf>
                <ref>S123</ref>
                <fs>APCT</fs>
            </rec>
            <rec id="2222_2">
               <t>N</t>
                <cf>AS</cf>
                <ref>S1231</ref>
                <fs>APCT</fs>
            </rec>
            <rec id="2222_3">
               <t>N</t>
                <cf>AS</cf>
                <ref>S1232</ref>
                <fs>APCT</fs>
            </rec>
        </recs>
        <Ag>acv</Ag>
    </rf>
 </rfs>
```

I need to get the all the nodes with `<fs>HD</fs>`
So my output should be like -

```
<rfs>
    <rf id="1111">
        <FO>Al</FO>
        <recs>
            <rec id="1111_2">
               <t>N</t>
                <cf>AS</cf>
                <ref>S1231</ref>
                <fs>HD</fs>
            </rec>
            <rec id="1111_3">
               <t>N</t>
                <cf>AS</cf>
                <ref>S1232</ref>
                <fs>HD</fs>
            </rec>
        </recs>
        <Ag>XYZ</Ag>
    </rf>
 </rfs>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Well, you are supposed to show us your attempt and how it failed. And I am not sure the sample is a precise specification, how do you decide which elements to copy and which ones not? The `<FO>Al</FO>` or `<Ag>XYZ</Ag>` in your wanted output are not having that descendant `<fs>HS</fs>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following templates:

```
  <xsl:template match="text()" />
  
  <xsl:template match="/rfs | rf[recs/rec/fs='HD']" >
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="FO | @* | text()" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="rec[fs='HD']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

They are neither complete nor perfect. But they are probably a good starting point for your endeavor.